# Mysql + Php + .htaccess rewrite URL

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb3

My url have this format "http://www.mybox.com/post.php?sid=XXXXXXXXXX" and I want to make a "filter" that replaced the sid value for another value that is on MySql and redirect to that new url.

There is a way to do that on .htaccess? Can I make sql querys from .htaccess??
I'm really new on this, so the help will be apreciated.

Comment: Where is the code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:phpbb3]?  Is `post.php` one of its files?  Is `sid` its session identifier?  If so, why ever would you *want* to change it?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Moreover, why are you trying to do it within `.htaccess` and not within PHP?

Comment: I'm working with phpbb3 (it is a forum) and what I want to avoid is a bug that I found today. If a user copy and paste the sid on the URL, can impersonate another user and post in his name. So my idea was to check the URL on each request and make sure that the sid on the URL is the one is save it on DB. I have no idea how to work with this, but it was the first idea that came to my mind.

Comment: @Anita: So if `sid=1` belongs to me and `sid=2` belongs to you; and I make a request with `sid=2`, how do you propose to identify that the request has come from me and not you?  The `sid` *is* the means by which users are identified - the fact that one can impersonate another user by spoofing their `sid` is not a "bug" but a design limitation.  However, it's pretty difficult to guess another user's `sid`...

Comment: There is an option to remove ?sid=...  from the links - at least it was some time ago.

Comment: If cookies are not set correctly, removing or changing the sid (session id) will log users out. If cookies are set correctly then the sid is only used for the first page load then the cookie takes over.

Comment: Is not hard to find the sid if it is appended to each url that the forums generate. Since this app was modify from the original forums code, it use this parameter for everything related with user validation, so is not an option to remove it. The solution that all posting offers (change request_order to GPC) doesn't work. My final gold is to instercept the http request, check if the sid is correct, if it is correct, continue with the request flow.. if it is not.. replace the sid for the correct one.. or abort the request..